# Excel Data Reading issue in C#

Tags: c#, asp.net, excel, datareader, exceldatareader

I am doing to create a page in which I can read data from excel sheet and upload in database, If all columns have value then there is no issue, while facing issue when some column not have values!

This is my code

```
if ((this.drp_Sheet.SelectedValue == "Well Test") && this.fileuploader.HasFile)
                {
                    try
                    {
                        string fileName = Path.GetFileName(fileuploader.FileName);
                        string extension = Path.GetExtension(fileName);
                        fileuploader.SaveAs(base.Server.MapPath("~/Files/") + fileName);
                        string FilePath2 = base.Server.MapPath("~/Files/") + fileName;
                        DataTable table5 = new DataTable();
                        DataSet set5 = new DataSet();
                        if (extension.Contains(".xlsx") || extension.Contains(".xls") || extension.Contains(".xlsm"))
                        {
                            
                            IExcelDataReader excelReader = ExcelReaderFactory.CreateOpenXmlReader(fileuploader.FileContent); 
                            
                            set5 = excelReader.AsDataSet();
                            table5 = set5.Tables[0];
                            grv_WellTest.DataSource = table5;
                            grv_WellTest.DataBind();
                            Session["DT_WELLTEST"] = table5;
                        }
                    }
                    catch (Exception exception6)
                    {
                        this.Info.Text = exception6.Message;
                    }
                    finally
                    {
                        dt_Out.Rows.Clear();
                        dt_tmp.Rows.Clear();
                    }
```

My excel data sheet is look like this
[image]

While reading excel file I populatas data set values in a gridview at user end for checking, but missing some column values which is written on red color as
[image]

Why the values are missing I can't find any clue. I change excel sheet, written values on new excel sheet and try to read values but same issue occur. Please help me out this unresolved issue please

Comment: what did you try to solve this problem? did you check to see if the column really returns a value when reading it using the ExcelReaderFactory? Please provide a full working example, with input data in TEXT format, no pictures.

Comment: Yes I checked in ExcelReaderFactory dataset, values are missing at that level!

Comment: Is there maybe anything special about those values in excel?

Comment: Nothing special, I check while changing values to text format, but issue remain same

Comment: Hi - Make sure you are using latest version of ExcelDataReader. If you are already on latest version, you should report this in their issue tracker at Github. Most importantly, remember to provide your Excel file so they (I) can reproduce.